# Can I get the given plot without calculating the roots numerically? Is it possible to use Manipulate/Animate to get a continuous line of the points?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, numerics, animation

I have two functions $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ for $0<x\leq3$ and $-1\leq y \leq1$. Given a specific value of $y$, I want to find those values of $x$ for which we have $F=0$ and $G\neq \pm 1$.

For example, for $y=-1$, using `NSolve`, I get

```
y := -1;

F := -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) -  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

G := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[ 3 x])/(2 x);

NSolve[F == 0 && 0 < x < 3 , x]
(*{{x -> 1.0472}, {x -> 1.12061}, {x -> 1.37163}, {x -> 1.88921}, {x ->  2.0944}}*)

NSolve[G == 1 && 0 < x < 3 , x]
(*{{x -> 0.510074}, {x -> 1.30826}, {x -> 1.5708}, {x -> 2.0944}, {x ->  2.44336}}*)

NSolve[G == -1 && 0 < x < 3 , x]
(* {{x -> 0.898222}, {x -> 1.0472}, {x -> 1.5708}, {x -> 1.86278}, {x ->  2.86912}} *)
```

hence, desired roots for $x$ are  `{  {x -> 1.12061}, {x -> 1.37163}, {x -> 1.88921} }`. Then, I can show these points together with my original functions $F$ and $G$, using this code

```
p1 := Plot[{F, G}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 300, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> Automatic];

p2 = ListPlot[{  {1.1206084032394001`,   1.5 }   , {1.3716304436307527`,  1.5   } , {1.889214526133747`  ,   1.5  }     },  PlotMarkers -> {"\[Diamond]", Large}, PlotStyle -> Red]  ;

Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

as this picture

[image]

**I have two questions:**

> Is there any way to get this picture without calculating the precise values of the roots (which we did by`NSolve`)? I mean something like using a conditional plot.

> If the answer to the above question is YES, then, is it possible to use `Manipulate`/ `Animate` to get a continuous line of these red points when $y$ changes from $-1$ to $1$?

**Ex. 1**

```
F := -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) + Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/ x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

G := Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x];

With[{rat =  F /. {{f_ :> f}, {r : Sqrt[_] :> -r}} // Apply@Times // Expand // Simplify, F = F, G = G},  Manipulate[ Normal@Plot[{F, G}, {x, 4, 5}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 500, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {x, rat}}, MeshStyle -> Blue,  
Mesh -> {{0}}] /.   Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, z_Real} :> {x, 0.5}] // 
DeleteCases[#,  Point[{x0_, _}] /; Abs[F /. x -> x0] > 0.1  ||  Abs[G^2 -1 /. x -> x0] < 0.01 ,  Infinity ] &, {y, 1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Normal@Plot[{F, G}, {x, 0, 3},
   PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> Automatic,
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[x, Re@F // Evaluate]} // Evaluate, 
   MeshStyle -> Red, Mesh -> {{0}}] /. 
 Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, 1.5}]
```

[image]

One of the roots of `F` is not a simple root and `F` does not cross zero at it; hence the mesh functions miss it.

*Update*

```
Clear[x, y];
With[{rat = 
   F /. {{f_ :> f}, {r : Sqrt[_] :> -r}} // Apply@Times // Expand // 
    Simplify, F = F, G = G},
 Manipulate[
  Normal@Plot[{F, G}, {x, 0, 3},
      PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
      MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ {x, rat}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
      Mesh -> {{0}}] /.
    Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, z_Real} :> {x, 1.5}] // 
   DeleteCases[#, 
    Point[{x0_, _}] /; Abs[F /. x -> x0] > 0.1 || Abs[G^2 - 1 /. x -> x0] < 0.01,
    Infinity] &,
  {y, -5, 0}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Not sure why `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` is needed to get a quality plot.  (Some points are dropped if `"Quality"` is specified, even though no points are lost if evaluated outside `Manipulate`.)

Comment: To get all 5 points: `rat = F /. {{f_ :> f}, {r : Sqrt[_] :> -r}} // Apply@Times // Expand // Simplify;
Normal@Plot[{F, G}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, (*...*)
    MeshFunctions -> {Function[x, rat // Evaluate]} // Evaluate, Mesh -> {{0}}] /.
  Point[p_] :> Point[p /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x, 1.5}] // 
 DeleteCases[#, Point[{x0_, _}] /; Abs[F /. x -> x0] > 0.1, Infinity]  &`

Comment: Thanks you indicate that  why the mesh missing two points!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much for the answer. I get an empty answer by copying and pasting your code in the comment.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your animated picture is exactly the one I was looking for. But I have two other questions, I will be very grateful if you help me: 1. is it possible to have a trajectory of the movement of the red points as $y$ changes? I mean something like a continuous line that shows their changes. 2. Can we exclude those two red points (the first one on the left and the last one on the right) from your manipulate code? They correspond to the case $G=\pm1$; in other words, in general, can we exclude the solutions of  $G=\pm1$ for your manipulation code?

Comment: @math2021 I got rid of $G=\pm1$, but for the trajectories, you would either have to calculate the zeros for all $y$ in a range or save them from each calculation & plot all the saved  perhaps connected with `Line[]` (though if you scrub the slider back and forth quickly, you'll probably create a mess). Another issue is that around $y=-\pi$ there is only one root, so tracing three trajectories through that singularity poses a challenge.

Comment: @math2021 The following calculates the trajectories of the zeros, somehow avoiding the singularity (lucky round-off error?). You asked not to numerically solve for the roots, but why not share the idea?: `ics = Times @@ Subtract @@@ Flatten@NSolve[F == 0 && 0 < x < Pi && G^2 != 1 /. x -> x[y] /. y -> -2 Pi, x[-2 Pi]] == 0;

x /. NDSolve[{Equal @@@ First@Solve[D[F /. x -> x[y], y] == 0, x'[y]], ics}, x, {y, -2 Pi, 0}] // ListLinePlot` --- If it seems a feasible approach, we could go into it further.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you again; since I have to do this for various situations and it is somehow impossible to deal with them numerically.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have another question (a bit long as a comment) related to this post; shall I ask it as a new question, or I can add it to the text of this question?

Comment: It’s almost always better to ask a new question, especially after several people have already answered the first question. (Also, what if person A gives the best answer to question 1 and a bad answer to Q2 while person B gives the best answer to Q2 and a bad answer to Q1? Our votes cannot really mark which is the best answer to both or to each, and the votes are supposed to help guide future visitors.)

Comment: @math2021 The `|| Abs[G^2 - 1 /. x -> x0] < 0.01` (where `||` means `Or`) deletes any value of `x0` where the value of `G^2` at `x` equal to `x0` is closer to `1` than `0.01`. Add the same with `H` (or whatever) instead of `G`. (You can change the `0.01` if needed. Since the values generated by `Plot` are only roughly approximate, you have to pick a threshold.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry to take your time again; I followed your suggestion but the problem still persists. I have added **Ex.1** (almost the same as the original one) at the end of my question, I use your code but it does not exclude those points in which $G\neq1$. I will be very grateful if you could kindly let me know your idea on how to solve this problem. It would really help me in my project; otherwise, I cannot use all the data you and others kindly shared here.

Comment: @math2021 I think it's probably working. Here's my test: `Block[{y = 1.674, sol}, sol = NSolve[F == 0 && 4 < x < 5 /. y -> 1.3, x]; Thread[{sol, G /. sol}]]`, where the `1.674` was obtained from the `Manipulate` from a setting I doubted.  The output from `Block[...]` shows four roots, two of should be excluded because `G` equaled `1.` and `1.00001`. Now possibly `Plot` did not find both roots near `4.19`, but even with `PlotPoints -> 1500`, which should have found both roots, they also should be excluded, which they are. Can you give a value of `y` that fails? And give the right answer?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks again. Maybe you are right and maybe I have mixed two questions that may be different. My original idea of this question was to find the intersection points of two curves, say $A$ and $B$, but to make it simpler, I asked for the roots of the equation $A-B=0$ instead. Now, I see that the results may be slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

## Review

- **y=-1**

Except `NSolve` or `Reduce`, none of the other three methods can include all the root!
We can compare the four pictures.

```
f[x_, y_] = -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];
g[x_, y_] = 
  Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[
       3 x])/(2 x);
fig1 = Plot[f[x, -1], {x, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> {{f[x, -1] == 0}}, 
   ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thin], Directive[Red, Thick]},
    PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]; (* Method by Edmund *)
fig2 = Plot[f[x, -1], {x, 0, 3}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
fig3 = With[{plot = Plot[{f[x, -1], 0}, {x, 0, 3}]}, 
   Show[plot, 
    Graphics[{Red, 
      Point[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot, 
        Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> True]]}], PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]];
fig4 = Plot[f[x, -1], {x, 0, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, 
     Point[{#, 0} & /@ 
       Evaluate@NSolveValues[{f[x, -1] == 0, 0 < x <= 3}, x]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
GraphicsGrid[{{fig1, fig2}, {fig3, fig4}}]
```

[image]

- **y=1/2**

```
f[x, y] /. {x -> π/3, y -> 1/2}
f[x, y] /. {x -> 2π/3, y -> 1/2}
```

> `0`

[image]

**Edit**

Not so perfect.

```
Clear[F, G, fig];
F[x_, y_] = -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];
G[x_, y_] = 
  Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[
       3 x])/(2 x);
fig[y_] := 
  Module[{plotF, plotG, ptsF, ptsG}, 
   plotF = Plot[{F[x, y], 0}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Gray}];
   ptsF = 
    Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plotF, 
     Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> True];
   plotG = Plot[{G[x, y], 0}, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Gray}];
   (*ptsG=Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plotG,
   Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints->True];*)
   Show[plotG, plotF, 
    Graphics[{Red, Point[TranslationTransform[{0, 1.5}] /@ ptsF], 
      Green, Point[{{π/3, 0}, {2 π/3, 0}}]}]]];
Manipulate[fig[y], {y, -1, 1}, ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Clear[F, G];
F = -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];

G = Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[
       3 x])/(2 x);

Reduce[{F == 0, G == 1, 0 < x <= 3, -1 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]
Reduce[{F == 0, G == -1, 0 < x <= 3, -1 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

> `x == (2 π)/3 && -1 <= y <= 1`

> `x == π/3 && -1 <= y <= 1`

It means that if we want to get `F==0,G!=1,G!=-1`, we just need to exclude `x == (2 π)/3` and `x == π/3`  in `F==0`.

```
Clear[F, G, y];
F = -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) - 
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/
         x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2];
G = Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[
       3 x])/(2 x);
y = -1;
Plot[{F, G}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, InfiniteLine[{π/3, 0}, {0, 1}], 
   InfiniteLine[{2 π/3, 0}, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style["x=π/3", Red], {π/3, 5}, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["x=2π/3", Red], {2 π/3, 5}, {-1, -1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  My question was to show those three red points (in the picture attached to the text) without calculating their precise values numerically; something like using the conditional plots (or any other ways that I am unaware of) for $F=0$ and $G\neq\pm1$. Since my problem is much more complicated in the general case, and, it is not easy to deal with them numerically; and, in the next step, manipulating those results for different values of $y$. @cvgmt

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) option of [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

First define your functions with [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) to prevent variable scope issues.

```
Clear[f, g, x, y]
f[x_, y_] := -((3 Sin[3 x])/(2 x)) - 
  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 x] + (2 Sin[3 x])/x + (Cos[2 x] - Cos[y]) Csc[2 x] Sin[3 x])^2]
g[x_, y_] := Cos[3 x] + ((1 + 2 x Cot[2 x] - x Cos[y] Csc[x] Sec[x]) Sin[3 x])/(2 x)
```

The `Exclusions` spec for `y = -1` can be satisfied by

```
{f[x, -1] == 0, g[x, -1] != 1 && g[x, -1] != -1}
```

Included in `Plot`

```
Plot[
 {f[x, -1], g[x, -1]}
 , {x, 0, 3}
 , Exclusions -> {{f[x, -1] == 0, g[x, -1] != 1 && g[x, -1] != -1}}
 , ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thin], Directive[Red, Thick]}
 , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
 , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The red markers appear on the plot curves instead of floating.  However, this is easy to [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {f[x, my], g[x, my]}
  , {x, 0, 3}
  , Exclusions -> {{f[x, my] == 0, g[x, my] != 1 && g[x, my] != -1}}
  , ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Green, Thin], Directive[Red, Thick]}
  , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
  , PlotLegends -> {Inactive[f][x, my], Inactive[g][x, my]}
  ]
 , {{my, -1, "y"}, -1, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that the `Exclusions` spec can be used to simplify solving the x values if you want to go the [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) route with [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html).

```
xvalues = NSolveValues[{f[x, -1] == 0, g[x, -1] != 1 && g[x, -1] != -1 && 0 < x < 3}, x]
```

> ```
> {1.12061, 1.37163, 1.88921}
> ```

Then

```
Plot[
 {f[x, -1], g[x, -1]}
 , {x, 0, 3}
 , Exclusions -> {{f[x, -1] == 0, g[x, -1] != 1 && g[x, -1] != -1}}
 , ExclusionsStyle -> None
 , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
 , PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
 , Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ xvalues}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.